# Ember js check for key value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have an users array which consists of 4 user objects.

```
users: [
        {
            id: 1,
            user_id: 10116,
            email: "xx.xx@gmail.com",
            password: "xx.xx@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            user_id: 10117,
            email: "yy@gmail.com",
            password: "yy@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            user_id: 10126,
            email: "bangalore@aurus.com",
            password: "bangalore@aurus.com"
        }
    ]

var myEmail = "xx.xx@gmail.com";
var myPassword = "xx.xx@gmail.com";
```

What is the shortest way to check wether a particular `myEmail` & `myPassword` exists/matches in the given `users` array.

Is there any Ember way of doing this ?

I have tried using the `forEach` loop and trying to check for values. I am looking for an optimal soluton.

Thx

Comment: forEach is the correct one

Comment: By 'optimal' solution do you mean 'most concice' or 'most efficient', or something else?

Comment: @bvl yes forEach works, but is there any one line solution that would find me which user object contains the given email and password?

Comment: @ChrisHodges basically I don't want to manually loop over the array and check for the key value pairs. Is there any inbulit function that would do this ?

Comment: @Ajey There is no one line solution, but there is a very useful method to do what you want... Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite one line, but using just inbuilt Javascript, the most concise I can come up with is:

```
var user = users.filter(function (element) {
  return element.email == myEmail && element.password == myPassword;
})[0];
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dqMLG/

Answer (score 1):

Before I answer, a word of caution. You are putting your users at extreme risk by exposing passwords in any form to the client. Doesn't matter how you encrypted them or whatever.

That said, you are likely looking for `.any` http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_any

It will return true (boolean) if your condition matches one or more items in the enumeration. I often use this in computed properties. For example, here is what it might look like it you were looping that collection into a template and you wanted to work within an item controller:

```
matchedEmailAndPassword: function () {
  return this.get('users').any(function (item) {
    return item.get('email') === this.get('email') && item.get('password') === this.get('password');
}.property('email', 'password')
```

I wouldn't actually use that computed property, it's just pseudo code.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is just a test case, it does not actually mean I am trying to expose user passwords on the client side.

Comment: @Ajey Ah, sounds good. I'll leave my answer as-is just in case someone reads this question in the future. Did `.any` work for you?

Comment: Yes works fine. Came to realize there are other ember array helpers too.